# writing an $httpProvider for a long-polling comet app

Tags: angularjs, promise, comet, long-polling, angular-promise

**TL;DR:** Are there examples of Angular with long-polling integration out there? (Examples, specifically Comet examples would be nice!)

Our current app uses Angular and Comet. The client sends out long-polling requests that stay open until the server has data to return. When the server returns data, the data payload might have several messages for different 'channels'.

The out-of the box Comet JS code we have uses jQuery's `$.get(), $.post()` methods to make the long-polling requests.

Angular is built on a light version of jQuery and adds lots of (Angular-related) magic compared to `$.get()/$.post()` via Angular's `$http` object.

I've been told the Angular's `$http` object and the promises it returns are not compatible with message-based front-ends, but I'm not convinced

Is it true they are incompatible?

I was thinking a different `$httpProvider` that is Comet aware could be written, that would provide an $http object, that based on URL could determine if it should behave in normal ajax mode or long-poll mode.

The idea here is that typically each Comet channel has a message listener and the listener has a callback it invokes passing in the message.

To me this seems like a promise in disguise. Generally, the idea would be to create a promise for each channel. When the $http object is dealing with a long-poll request, when the server responds with data it would know how to parse the payload into messages for each channel, and then resolve each channel (which is now a promise in Angular world). Resolving each channel would have the effect of calling the channels/promises then() function.

Doesn't this achieve message-based behavior with listeners and callbacks? Are these just the same things, but with different names?

I'm considering toying with the approach and possibly prototyping it. But before I do, does this even make sense?

How these promises would resolve in Angular HTML templates I'm still uncertain about.

Are there already examples of Angular with long-polling integration out there?

I couldn't find any.

Comment: `$http` returns promises - a single operation, your long polling example sounds like Angular 2.0 observables. I don't think there are _solid_ examples of this - if you'd show me how you do it with jquery and/or native XHR I can help you port that to Angular.

Comment: thank you. we can possibly get some code examples. we do have a comet jquery wrapper that does this.

Comment: Can you _show me some code_ :)?

Comment: not sure, it's a 'sensitive' area... :-) let me get back on this.

Comment: It doesn't need to be your actual code (in fact it better not be) - it should be a really isolated example _illustrating_ what you're doing.

Comment: yes, right. the wrapper code we have comes from another company and has been lightly obfuscated. i haven't seen the actual written code other than the obfuscated stuff. so it'll take some time to get the actual code, dumb it down to a toy example and get it to you. honestly, thanks for your enthusiasm! just never enough time in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Does this even make sense?", not quite.

It would appear that what you need client-side is :

### Fixed

- a set of fixed Angualr listeners (maybe one per channel, but potentially one per message-type per channel).

### Per polling cycle

1. a long-poll initiator / listener
2. a message bundle parser / event broadcaster

As I read the question, it seems that you may not have made a clear distinction between (1) and (2).

(1) will be a `$http()` request, which returns a promise.

(2) will be a bespoke function, called whenever such as request is satisfied (whenever a promise becomes fulfilled).

Thus, each polling cycle will comprise strictly *one promise*, but *one or more broadcast events*, which will be responded to by the fixed listeners.

It's like a scatter-gun, which fires a cartridge of pellets every time its trigger is pulled (and a set of willing targets that enjoy being shot).

Please note that at this level of definition, the whole thing is conceptually identical to regular short-polling, from which long-polling differs only in the timing of the requests and responses (such that the server is in apparent control).

Comment: thank you. this actually sounds very viable. digesting... :-)

Comment: apologies, took me  a long time to get back around to this. but yes, this idea is spot on.